# LFW nested folder iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to flip some images in the LFW Face Dataset. However, the solution I thought of didn't work as planned

```
for folder in listdir('lfw/'):
    a = chdir('/' + folder )
    for file in a:
        spin(file)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What does "didn't work as planned" mean? Please elaborate on what your issue with your code is

Comment: It seemed intuitive enough to write the folder iteration code, but I was getting errors. Sorry for the confusion!